# Is a set initialized with a list of elements guaranteed to retain the first instance of each unique element by order of said list?

Tags: python

Consider the following scenario:

```py
class Class():
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
    def __hash__(self):
        return 1

a = Class()
b = Class()
# a == b -> True

a.property = "a"
b.property = "b"

l = list(set([a, 2, b]))
print(l[0].property)


l = list(set([b, 2, a]))
print(l[0].property)
```

Is the output guaranteed to be "a" in the first print, and "b" in the second? That is, are N elements fed to a set's initialization guaranteed to be processed in the order of the input, with only the sequential duplicates discarded afterwards? And if yes, where can I see the implementation of this initialization?

Comment: The argument to the `set()` constructor is an iterable. Since it's not possible to iterate out of order, I don't see how it could do anything but add them in order.

Comment: Note that the documentation of `set.add()` doesn't say that it won't replace an element with an equal element.

Comment: Note that `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'property'` is also an allowable outcome of your `print`s, since sets make no guarantees of iteration order.

Comment: Yeah that's the kind of issues I'm looking a definite answer for. I'd like to know for sure what the actual behavior is. I couldn't find anything verifiable with a search so far.